# How to use nullable built-in variables in LINQ?

Tags: c#, linq

I'm very new LINQ, and I've a question regarding it here.

I have this very simple class here for demonstration purposes:

```
public class CurrencyPair
{
    public string? cultureCode;
    public string? currencyName;

    public CurrencyPair(string iCultureCode, string iCurrencyName)
    {
        cultureCode = iCultureCode;
        currencyName = iCurrencyName;
    }

    public CurrencyPair()
    {
        cultureCode = "";
        currencyName = "";
    }
}
```

Then I have a List of instances of the above Class:

```
static List<CurrencyPair> currencyPairs;
```

Now I'm trying to do this:

```
public List<string> GetCurrencyNames()
{
    return (from c in currencyPairs select c.currencyName).Distinct().ToList();
}
```

However I get this error:

```
The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type in order to use it as parameter 'T' in the generic type or method 'System.Nullable<T>'
```

If I remove the `?` for `cultureCode` and `currencyName` in the class definition, this error goes away.

So how can I use nullable strings in LINQ queries .. ?

Answer (score 8, accepted):

`string` is already a **reference type**, it can hold `null`, you don't have to use `string?`

The error is indicating that as well:

> The type 'string' must be a non-nullable value type....

You can only use `Nullable<T>` with value types.

[`Nullable<T>`](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/b3h38hb0.aspx)

> Represents **a value type** that can be assigned null.

You are trying to declare field with `string?` which is equal to `Nullable<string>`, but this can only be done with [value types](http://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/s1ax56ch.aspx).

> In C# and Visual Basic, you mark a value type as nullable by using the
>   ? notation after the value type. For example, int? in C# or Integer?
>   in Visual Basic declares an integer value type that can be assigned
>   null

.

Comment: Yup, sorry it was my mistake. I guess I forgot `string` actually does support `null` value. Thanks anyways.